# Как изменить жирность шрифта в теге option?

Tags: html, css

Вот код HTML:

```
<select class="grey" size="1" name="prof"  >
          
<option value="" hidden></option>
            <option class="black" value=""> <h3> <span class="weight"> Банки, инвестиции, лизинг</span></h3</option>

            <option value=""></option>
        <option class="black" value=""> Валютный контроль</option>
        <option class="black" value="">Кредиты</option>
        <option value="">Безопастность</option>
        <option  class="black" value="">Административный персонал</option>
        <option class="black"  value="">Архивист</option>
        <option class="black" value="">Водитель</option>
        <option value="">Вечерний секретарь</option>
        <option value="">Высший менеджмент</option>
        <option value="">Директор</option>
        <option value="">Главный бухгалтер</option>

        </select></h2>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
}

.sel {
  width: 55px;
}

textarea {
  width: 450px;
  height: 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

option {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.ds {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.grey {
  color: gray;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.weight {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: span {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
}

select {
    width: 200px;
}

.sel {
    width: 55px;
}

textarea {
    width: 450px;
    height: 15px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

option {
    font-weight: 500;
    
}


.ds {
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

.grey {
    color: gray;
}

.black {
    color: black;
}

.weight {
    font-weight: 600;
}

Comment: У тебя `html` в примере не полный...

Answer (score -1):

```
option {
  font-weight: bold !important ; 
}
```

Comment: А зачем `!important`?

Comment: Это на всякий случчаи перебить важность, На усмотрение, не важно

Answer (score -1):

```css
option {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select class="grey" size="1" name="prof"  >
          
<option value="" hidden></option>
            <option class="black" value=""> <h3> <span class="weight"> Банки, инвестиции, лизинг</span></h3</option>

            <option value=""></option>
        <option class="black" value=""> Валютный контроль</option>
        <option class="black" value="">Кредиты</option>
        <option value="">Безопастность</option>
        <option  class="black" value="">Административный персонал</option>
        <option class="black"  value="">Архивист</option>
        <option class="black" value="">Водитель</option>
        <option value="">Вечерний секретарь</option>
        <option value="">Высший менеджмент</option>
        <option value="">Директор</option>
        <option value="">Главный бухгалтер</option>

        </select>
```